# How Android manages screen?

Tags: android, screen

I'm just curious look at [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Galaxy Note falls under normal size and XHDPI
Sony Xperia S falls under normal size and XHDPI

But how come in real device the layout look different on each device? How I provide layout for each Android device out there?

Comment: have you tested the example given in your link in 2 emulators or phones with different displays? it can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can ever make a layout that will suit every Android device. I find the best results are by:
(1) Using `RelativeLayout`s
(2) Avoiding use of any hardcoded dimensions, instead using `wrap_content` and `fill_parent` where possible

I build three main layouts: `normal`, `small` and `large`, and I use as many as five sets of graphics for different screen densities and sizes.

It's a challenge!

Comment: Hi, I used RelativeLayout, wrap_content and fill_parent with some dp value but no pixels used. I also have layout for normal and large. layout-ldpi, layout-mdpi, layout-xhdpi. Galaxy Note and Xperia S will be using layout-xhdpi. Can you tell me what are 5 sets graphic you are using? Now I just realized is it the width dimension 720 against 800 that matters...

Comment: I'm just learning myself, but my five graphic sets are: ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi and large-mdpi. My three layouts are layout, layout-small, and layout-large. My drawable-xhdpi and drawable-large-mdpi are exactly the same dimensions, but i need to create the separate folder so they work right for tablet.